# Search method for tree with multiple children per node

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, tree

I created the following Method to search for a certain ParentReference Id in a Tree that is unsorted and where every node can have any number of children. If the given parentRef matches the Node's parentRef, the Node should be returned.

```
public static <T>Node<T> search(Node<T> node, int parentRef) {
    if(node.getParentRef() == parentRef){
        return node;
    }
    if(node.getChildren()!= null){
        for(int i = 0; i < node.getChildren().size(); i++){
            if(node.getChildren().get(i).parentRef == parentRef){
                return node;
            }
            else {
                search(node.getChildren().get(i), parentRef);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

However, it does not work and always returns `null` but I don't know why. Can anybody explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Bax Yes it does.

Comment: `[help-me]` "Does not work" is not enough to go on. Please explain exactly what happens and/or does not happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `else` branch, you call `search` recursively, but don't return its value, so it is lost. You should check if it's not `null`, and if so, return it:

```
else {
    Node<T> result = search(node.getChildren().get(i), parentRef);
    if (result != null) {
        return result;
    }
}
```